# Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.site_master' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button'. in asp.net

Tags: c#

I just created ten buttons and last two buttons named btn_green and btn_red,.

I wanna to change all button color to the green and red when click those buttons green and red.

My C# code is

```
protected void btn_green_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Button btn in this.Controls)
            {
                btn.BackColor = Color.DarkGreen;
            }
        }     

        protected void btn_red_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Button btn in this.Controls)
            {
                btn.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
```

but my bed luck i got only error

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object
>   of type 'ASP.site_master' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button'.

```
Line 20:             foreach (Button btn in this.Controls)
```

how i escape this problem?.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (Button btn in this.Controls)
```

returns **all** control in your page, not just your buttons. You need to cast it to button or try its type before accessing it.

```
foreach (Control control in Controls)
{
    var btn = control as Button;
    if (btn != null)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use `if(control is Button)` as well

Answer (score 1):

The 'foreach' doesn't filter the controls to return all buttons. Rather it loops through all controls and tries to cast them to Button. That fails if it's not a button.

Plus (and that may not be a problem in your case) `this.Controls` will only return Controls directly under 'this' and not nested inside some container. If you also want controls at a deeper lever, you will need a recursive function.

If you don't need recursion, you can use Linq:

```
foreach(Button btn in Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
   btn.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the type of control before using it as a button since Form.Control returns all controls in the form.

Try following code block

```
    foreach (Control objControl in this.Controls)
    {
        if (objControl is Button)
        {
            (objControl as Button).BackColor = Color.DarkGreen;

        }
    }
```